# XCode 4.4.1 - C++ - Apple Mach-O Linker (ID) Error - symbol (s) not found for architecture i386

Tags: c++, xcode, linker-errors

I've written some simple C++ programs in XCode 4.4.1 Whenever I compile them, I get the following errors:

```
"Main()", referenced from:
mainWrapper() in libStanfordCPPLib.a(startup.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Is it making a reference to `mainWrapper()` in `libStanfordCPPLib.a`? The latter file is supplied and is it possible to modify the content? Else, do i need to make to a change to eliminate the reference to `mainWrapper()`? Thanks.

**More details:**

```
Ld ./BlankProject.app/Contents/MacOS/BlankProject normal i386
    cd "/Users/benjamin/Documents/Programming/iTunes U/Stanford/CS106B Programming Abstractions/Summer 2012/Programs/Section Handout #2 Question 2"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -arch i386 "-L/Users/benjamin/Documents/Programming/iTunes U/Stanford/CS106B Programming Abstractions/Summer 2012/Programs/Section Handout #2 Question 2" -LStanfordCPPLib "-L/Users/benjamin/Documents/Programming/iTunes U/Stanford/CS106B Programming Abstractions/Summer 2012/Programs/Section Handout #2 Question 2/StanfordCPPLib" "-F/Users/benjamin/Documents/Programming/iTunes U/Stanford/CS106B Programming Abstractions/Summer 2012/Programs/Section Handout #2 Question 2" -filelist "/Users/benjamin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BlankProject-fxnhpjsyinnahlexvnlrhbilvwkd/Build/Intermediates/BlankProject.build/Debug/Section Handout #2 Question 4a.build/Objects-normal/i386/BlankProject.LinkFileList" -framework Cocoa -framework Carbon -framework QuickTime -lStanfordCPPLib -o "/Users/benjamin/Documents/Programming/iTunes U/Stanford/CS106B Programming Abstractions/Summer 2012/Programs/Section Handout #2 Question 2/./BlankProject.app/Contents/MacOS/BlankProject"

Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
"Main()", referenced from:
mainWrapper() in libStanfordCPPLib.a(startup.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Is this for OS X or iOS?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that whatever library you are using expects you to define a function called `Main()` (note the uppercase M), and you haven't done so.

Comment: Thanks @autopulated. I've defined a function called main(). Have changed it to Main() but still the error persists. Also, I've other programs that call the same library 'libStanfordCPPLib.a' and they compile without any problems-they have the function main().

Comment: @RexF If you have programs that do work, then the best thing to do might be to look at differences in the compilation settings between the projects.